# python: using networkX on biological networks for directional edges

Tags: python, networking, path, nodes, networkx

As the title says, I'm using networkX to represent some cell networks in Python.
The network is at the bottom of this post since it's a large image.

The reason I'm doing this is because some of theres nodes are considered "input" and some will be considered "output", and I need to be able to calculate the number of signal paths (the number of paths from input to output) that each node participates in. however, I don't think networkX offers edge directionality, which I believe is needed to calculate signal paths for nodes.

**Does anyone know if its possible to add direction to edges in networkX, or if its possible to calculate signal paths without directionality?**

Here's the code I wrote up until I realized I needed directional edges:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.Graph()
molecules = ["CD40L", "CD40", "NF-kB", "XBP1", "Pax5", "Bach2", "Irf4", "IL-4", 
"IL-4R", "STAT6", "AID", "Blimp1", "Bcl6", "ERK", "BCR", "STAT3", "Ag", "STAT5", 
"IL-21R", "IL-21", "IL-2", "IL-2R"]
Bcl6_edges = [("Bcl6", "Bcl6"), ("Bcl6", "Blimp1"), ("Bcl6", "Irf4")]
STAT5_edges = [("STAT5", "Bcl6")]
edges = Bcl6_edges + STAT5_edges
G.add_nodes_from(molecules)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

[image: cell network]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `G = nx.DiGraph()` for a directed graph.

Comment: I thought that was for something totally different, feel kinda stupid now. Regardless, thank you!